# homotopy type of box topology.

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is weakly equivalent to a point. Let $I$ be a set. Does $\prod_{i\in I}X$ weakly equivalent to a point, where $\prod_{i\in I}X$ is equipped with box topology ?

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209661/which-topological-properties-are-preserved-under-taking-box-products

Comment: @Gro-Tsen As far as I understand, your link is more about point set topology aspects of box topology...

Comment: what do you mean by "weakly equivalent to a point"?

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question in the comments above, (path) connectedness is not preserved by box product. For example, the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not (path) connected. Thus the answer to your question seems to be no.

Comment: But are there counterexamples (to being null-homotopic) when connectedness is preserved?